# Coordinates calculation: How to translate an object on a rotated HTML body respective to 0 degree rotation body

Tags: javascript, html, coordinate-systems

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I solved this problem using formulae from this post [Calculating the origin of a rotated HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079473/calculating-the-origin-of-a-rotated-html-element?rq=1)

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

This question is in continuation of my previous question below:
[How to translate Mouse X,Y Coordinates to move HTML element inside a container where container is rotated to some angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205161/how-to-translate-mouse-x-y-coordinates-to-move-html-element-inside-a-container-w)

Here is some background, if you did not read previous link:

I am making a card games in HTML/JS that shows real-time perspectives for all players.

For a 4 player table, table is rotated at 0, 90, 180 and 270 degress.

For a 6 player table is rotated into 6 sides as 0 degree, 60 degrees, 120 degrees, and up to 300 degrees.

The structure of table and cards on it is like this:

```
<gameTable style=”position: relative;”> 

<card style=”position: absolute; top: 1%, left: 1%;”></card> 

</gameTable>
```

The cards are absolutely positions so movements are uniform across all screen sizes.

Now I am making a function that allows me to store a setting of cards on the table and save them as objects. I calculate their offsets from current player and store them.

Offsets mean:

```
if Player = 0 degree, offsetY = 100 - card.top and OffsetX = 100 - card.left
```

Similary, I use formulae (brute method) to store offsets for other 3 players of 4 player table.

```
if Player = 180 degree, offsetY = card.top and OffsetX = card.left 
if Player = 90 degree, offsetY = card.left and OffsetX = 100 - card.top 
if Player = 270 degree, offsetY = 100 - card.left and OffsetX = card.top
```

I interchange values to store correct offsets and then whenever I want to display them again, I used same formulae to show them in correct positions, no matter which of the 4 players called it.

Basically, target is to store correct offsets no matter from where which angle side I store it, and then show correctly, no matter on which angle table side I use it.

Example: To position a card after extracting its object.

```
if player is 90 degree, card.left = offsetY and card.top = 100 - offsetX
```

Now this works perfectly for 4 player table where all players are orthogonal to each other.

However, when it comes to 6 player table, where each player has angle of 60 degrees between them, I an unable to solve it yet.

I tried couple of things but none got me anywhere yet. This is closest:

```
let cosTheta = Math.cos((Math.PI / 180) * (tableRotationInDegrees));
let cosTheta = Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * (tableRotationInDegrees));
card.style.left = `${offsetX * cosTheta}%`;
card.style.top = `${offsetY * sinTheta}%`;
```

I think the following link might contain answer to what I am looking for, but I did not really understand much, as I am not so good in Math unfortunately.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51111/calculating-point-on-a-circle-given-an-offset

Here are attached pictures for reference.[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to apply matrix calculations. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Caramiriel. I solved it using the method I mentioned in start of post for now :)